# Have any proposals been advanced for the analytic continuation of the divisor function?

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, divisors-multiples, arithmetic-functions, analytic-continuation

While I was working on the evaluation of a certain series, the following limit came up:

\begin{align} \lim_{n \to 1} \frac{d(n)-1}{n(n-1)} &= \lim_{n \to 1} \frac{d'(n)}{2n-1} \\
&= d'(1)  .\end{align}

Here, I used l'Hôpitals rule, and $d(\cdot)$ denotes the [divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) function. In order to compute the derivative of a function, one must know how it is defined on the real numbers.  Unfortunately, I have not found any proposals that described the notion of the analytic continuation for the divisor function so far. It seems that it is defined on $\mathbb{Z}$ only.

I did find [identities](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.03488) for $\sigma_{\alpha} (x)$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ and $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$. However, this is not what I am looking for. I seek to find a suitable expression for $\sigma_{\alpha} (x)$ when $\alpha = 0$, and real or complex arguments $x$.

I believe it may be possible to find such an extension of the divisor function, in part because such extensions have been found for the lowercase prime omega function. This arithmetic function is related to the divisor function. The continuation of the function is as [follows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function#Continuation_to_the_complex_plane): $$ \DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc} \omega(z) = \log_{2} \Bigg{(} \sum_{x=1}^{\lceil Re(z) \rceil} \sinc \Bigg{(} \prod_{y=1}^{\lceil Re(z) \rceil + 1 } (x^{2} + x - yz) \Bigg{)} \Bigg{)} ,$$ where $\sinc(\cdot)$ is the normalized sinc function.

**Question**: have any proposals been advanced for the analytic continuation of the divisor function, thereby extending the domain to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: The formula for $\omega(z)$ seems to be more of an approximation than an exact formula as it doesn't seem to exactly match $\omega(z)$ at most integer values of $z$ (with the exceptions of $z=0$ and $z=1$). The errors at $z=2$ and $z=3$ are $-0.000999437$ and $-0.000233918$ respectively. The error does seem to decrease in magnitude as $z$ increases in magnitude.

Comment: The Harmonic number function $H_z=\gamma+\psi^{(0)}(z+1)$ and Gamma function $\Gamma(z)$ might be better examples.

Comment: @StevenClark Hmm okay, that is odd, I didn't expect that. Did you do the calculations with the normalized sinc function?

Comment: No, that perhaps was my mistake. I'll look at it some more.

Comment: @StevenClark I could've been more clear as well, I'll put it in the question

Comment: Using the definition $sinc(z)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\sin (\pi  z)}{\pi  z} & z\neq 0 \\
 1 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}\right.$ does seem to provide an exact match at integer values of $z$, but the analytic continuation of $\omega(z)$ is pretty ugly in between integer values of $z$.

Comment: Have you seen the question and answers at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3230248/inversion-theorem-for-dirichlet-series? Perhaps an analytic formula for $\sigma_0(n)$ can be derived from inversion of the Dirichlet series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_0(n)\ n^{-s}=\zeta (s)^2$? Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3493770/an-entire-function-interpolating-mun.

Comment: You mention evaluation of a certain series: which one, and doesn't it give you some idea of the value of $d'(1)$ ? I love heuristic guesses, let me guess (and don't ask me why) $d'(1)=1.56061785204...$

Comment: Is section 3.1 of the paper at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.09818.pdf close to what you're looking for?

Comment: @StevenClark I'm not sure, I suspect not. These are expressions for the divisor function at integer arguments as well, no?

Comment: An attempt was made at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2223463/divisor-function-analytic-continuation

Comment: I'm not sure the formula in the paper is restricted to integer values of n. I believe the paper was written by the author of the first Math Stack Exchange question I linked to in an earlier comment, and the related second Math Stack Exchange question I linked to in the same comment claims to derive a formula for an entire function interpolating $\mu(n)$. As I understand it the downside of these formulas is they're extremely slow to converge.

Comment: @StevenClark Are you sure they converge everywhere?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I'm not sure, but that seems to be the claim. I haven't had much luck with verifying convergence, but as I understand it the formulas are extremely slow to converge. So while they may be of some theoretical interest, they don't seem to be of much practical value with respect to evaluations.

Comment: @StevenClark I found it practically impossible to approximate these expressions numerically. Partial sums grow very fast initially and then drop but, except for $\zeta$ itself, depending on precision chosen they either diverge or converge to zero. I wonder how the plots in that paper were obtained. It is also strange that according to these plots continuations of both $\mu$ and $\Lambda$ become zero at all half-integers.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე In the paragraph following the first graph of $mu(n)$ in section 4.1 the author indicates "Note we made the intercept 0 so the value at 0 doesn't differ from the other integers (re-moving successive terms from (5) or (6),  on index j,  doesn't affect the result for integer or half-integer n, as proved in (2))". Formulas (5) and (6) both seem to converge and evaluate similar for $|n|<1$, but don't seem to match the figure in the interval 0<n<1, so it appears the author has evaluated a modified version of formula (5) in the figure.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  I haven't had luck with extending the convergence of formula (5) much beyond the $-1\le n\le 1$. I'm not sure how the author "made the intercept 0" since formulas (5) and (6) both seem to converge to 4 at $n=0$. I suspect all of the formulas plotted by the author in the paper may have been modified versions of the formulas defined within the paper.

Comment: @StevenClark I now actually managed to make it converge. You may have a look here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRi5I.png - these are graphs of $4k$-th partial sums for (5). You see that e. g. to reach correct value of $\mu(5)$ you need to sum about 40 terms. The terms themselves also were tricky. The culprit was approximation of $\pi$, it seems that for good results when calculating the $i$th coefficient you need to use $\pi$ to about $2i$ decimal places.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Interesting. I have a simpler analytic formula for $\mu(x)$ valid for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and I just noticed that my formula seems to evaluate almost exactly the same as the figure in the paper.  I'm now wondering if my formula is related or somehow equivalent, so I think I'll ask a question on this topic.

Comment: @StevenClark Looking forward to see your question, please link here too in case I miss it

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Here is a link to my question in case you missed it: https://mathoverflow.net/q/394213.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the divisor function $d(n)=\sigma_0(n)$ can be analytically continued at least for $n\in\mathbb{R}$, but I'm not sure about $n\in\mathbb{C}$.

---

Consider the divisor summatory function defined in formula (1) below.

$$D(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x\sigma_0(n)\tag{1}$$

---

Now consider the analytic representation of $D_o(x)=\underset{\epsilon\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{D(x-\epsilon)+D(x+\epsilon)}{2}$ and it's first order derivative $D_o'(x)$ defined in formulas (2) and (3) below where the evaluation frequency $f$ is assumed to be a positive integer.

$$D_o(x)=\underset{N,f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \left(\frac{x}{n}-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{f\,n}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2 \pi k x}{n}\right)}{k}\right)\right)\right),\quad x>0\tag{2}$$

$$D_o'(x)=\underset{N,f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}\left(1+2\sum\limits_{k=1}^{f\,n}\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi k x}{n}\right)\right)\right),\quad x>0\tag{3}$$

---

Finally consider the function $f'(x)$ defined in formula (4) below which is a subset of the function $D_o'(x)$ defined in formula (3) above.

$$f'(x)=\underset{N,f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(2\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{f\,n}\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi k x}{n}\right)\right),\quad x>0\tag{4}$$

---

The function $f'(x)$ defined in formula (4) above evaluates exactly to $2\,f \sigma_0(n)$ when $x=n$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}\land|n|\le N\land n\ne 0$ which leads to the following analytic formula for $\sigma_0(x)$ where the evaluation frequency $f$ may be chosen to be any positive integer.

$$\sigma_0(x)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{f}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{f\,n}\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi k x}{n}\right)\right)\tag{5}$$

---

The following two figures illustrate formula (5) for $\sigma_0(x)$ above where Figure (1) is evaluated at $f=1$, Figure (2) is evaluated at $f=2$, and both figures are evaluated at $N=5$. The red discrete portions of the figures illustrate the value of $\sigma_0(x)$ at non-zero integer values of $x$. Note formula (5) for $\sigma_0(x)$ evaluates exactly correct when $x=n$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}\land|n|\le N\land n\ne 0$. Also note that formula (5) evaluates to $N$ at $x=0$, and therefore the evaluation of formula (5) at $x=0$ diverges to $\infty$ as $N\to\infty$ which is consistent with the fact that zero has an infinite number of divisors. I'll also note that when evaluated at $f=2$, formula (5) for $\sigma_0(x)$ evaluates exactly to zero when evaluated at half-integer values of $x$ which is illustrated in Figure (2) below.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (5) for sigma_0(x) evaluated at N=5 and f=1]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula (5) for $\sigma_0(x)$ evaluated at $N=5$ and $f=1$

---

[image: Illustration of formula (5) for sigma_0(x) evaluated at N=5 and f=2]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of formula (5) for $\sigma_0(x)$ evaluated at $N=5$ and $f=2$

---

The evaluation limit $N=5$ was used in Figures (1) and (2) above to illustrate that formula (5) for $\sigma_0(x)$ evaluates exactly correct when $x=n$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}\land|n|\le N\land n\ne 0$. I usually select a value of $N$ much greater than the largest magnitude of $x$ in the evaluation range which I think is generally desirable. Figure (3) below illustrates formula (5) for $\sigma_0(x)$ evaluated at $f=1$ and $N=100$ in the range $0<x<20.5$.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (5) for sigma_0(x) evaluated at f=1 and N=100]

**Figure (3)**: Illustration of formula (5) for $\sigma_0(x)$ evaluated at $f=1$ and $N=100$

---

The derivative $\sigma_0'(x)$ of formula (5) for $\sigma_0(x)$ above is illustrated in formula (6) below.

$$\sigma_0'(x)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(-\frac{2\pi}{f}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n^2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{f\,n} k \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi k x}{n}\right)\right)\tag{6}$$

---

Formula (6) for $\sigma_0'(x)$ above seems to be independent of the value of $f$ when evaluated at $x=1$ (see my related Math StackExchange [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4149867)), so Figure (4) below just illustrates formula (6) above for $\sigma_0'(1)$ evaluated at $f=1$ as a function of $N$. Note as $N$ increases $\sigma_0'(1)$ also increases in an almost linear manner implying $\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\sigma_0'(1)=\infty$.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (6) for sigma_0'(1) evaluated at f=1 as a function of N]

**Figure (4)**: Illustration of formula (6) for $\sigma_0'(1)$ evaluated at $f=1$ as a function of $N$

---

The following table illustrates the trend illustrated in Figure (4) above continues as the magnitude of $N$ increases.

---

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 N & \sigma_0'(1) \\
 10 & 6.96764 \\
 100 & 96.6867 \\
 1000 & 996.657 \\
 10000 & 9996.65 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: interesting answer, thank you. The value you obtain for $\sigma_{0}'(1) $ does not correspond with the value that I was anticipating though based on numerical calculations. In my calculations based on partial summations of a rational multiple zeta series, it should amount to approximately $0,0002$. Maybe your analytic continuation can or should be normalized somewhere?

Comment: The trigonometric sum is reminiscent of a Fourier series, perhaps one can consider the continuous analogue of the sum-based formulation for Fourier series by formulating it as an integral (see e.g. lectures 5 and 6 of: https://see.stanford.edu/Course/EE261 )

Comment: Is it clear that the $N$ limit is defined on non-integers and will be real analytic? I am in great doubt about the complex case as $\cos$ and $\sin$ grow exponentially in the imaginary direction. Also, what is the status of $f$? Does increasing it improve convergence?

Comment: After some experimenting - seems like your limit is infinite on any non-integer, regardless of $f$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I don't believe the evaluation limit $N$ affects the evaluation at a non-zero integer  $x=n$ which is less than or equal in magnitude to $N$ ($0<|x|\le N$), but you're correct that the evaluation limit $N$ affects the evaluation at non-integer values of $x$ as well as the evaluation at $x=0$. This is most noticeable for $|x|<1$ since using formula (5) $\mu(0)\to\infty$ as $N\to\infty$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Increasing the evaluation limit from $f=1$ to $f=m$ might improve convergence of formula (5) for $\sigma_0(x)$ in the range $\frac{1}{m}\le |x|<1$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Formula (5) for $\sigma_0(x)$ is based on formula (3) for $D_o'(x)$ which I believe converges (in a distributional sense) to $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sigma_0(n)\,\delta(x-n)$ as $N\to\infty\land f\to\infty$. Formula (3) only converges in a distributional sense as $N\to\infty\land f\to\infty$, but I'm not sure about the convergence of formula (5) when evaliuated at $f\to\infty$ as well as $N\to\infty$. Formula (5) is normalized with $\frac{1}{f}$ so perhaps using formula (5) $\sigma_0(x)\to 0$ as $N\to\infty\land f\to\infty$ for non-integer values of $x$?

Comment: Well you must specify regime more precisely. If you fix $f$ then $N\to\infty$ results in infinity, and if you fix $N$ then $f\to\infty$ results in zero, so the simple double limit does not exist, while I suspect that if you choose a path like $N=\nu(f)$ or $f=\phi(N)$ for some functions $\nu$, $\phi$ you may get virtually anything in between. And it is not clear to me whether there is such choice which gives you something analytic.

Comment: Can you keep $\sigma_0'(1)$ at bay manipulating $f$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე As I indicated in my question above, I believe $\sigma_0'(1)$ is independent of $f$, and I've also noticed more generally that $\sigma_0'(n)$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ seems to be independent of $f$ which surprised me a bit. Hopefully someone will post a proof (or disproof) in response to my question at Math StackExchange at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4149867.

Comment: But then it is hopeless, no? I mean, they all go to infinity as $N$ grows.

Comment: I believe the convergence of formula (5) for $\sigma_0(x)$ at non-integer values of $x$ is related to $\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}\right)$. I suspect if this limit converges to zero then using formula (5) $\sigma_0(x)\to 0$ as $N\to\infty\land f\to\infty$. I'm not sure the limit converges at all much less to zero, so perhaps formula (5) for $\sigma_0(x)$ doesn't really converge at non-integer values of $x$ which would be unfortunate.

Comment: I don't see how it would imply that but in any case the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) certainly diverges, it grows like $\log N$. And anyway there is no chance of it going to zero as it is positive and increases with $N$

Comment: @@მამუკაჯიბლაძე You're right. I should have recognized this is just the Harmonic series. $\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is the offset of formula (4) from formula (3), so formula (4) shifts more negative at non-integer values of $x$ as $N$ increases, but perhaps the normalization factor $\frac{1}{f}$ in formula (5) eliminates this effect as $f\to\infty$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I can make my analytic formula for $\mu(x)$ evaluate similar to formula (5) in the PDF file (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsRy8.jpg). This figure illustrates my formula in orange overlaid on formula (5) from the PDF in blue. Note the two formulas evaluate so closely that the evaluation of my formula pretty much hides the evaluation of the underlying formula (5) from the PDF. The red discrete evaluation points represent the value of $\mu(x)$ at integer values of $x$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I can also make my formula evaluate similar to the first figure illustrated on page (7) of the PDF: see https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lt3X.jpg. I'm still trying to figure out how the author of the PDF manipulated formula (5) from the PDF to converge to zero at $n=0$. I'd like to plot my formula overlaid on the authors modified formula to see if our versions that converge to $0$ at the origin match as closely as our versions that converge to $4$ at the origin. Do you have any ideas on how the author manipulated formula (5) in the PDF to converge to $0$ at $n=0$?

Comment: He simply omits the $j=0$ summand, i. e. takes $\sum_{j=1}^i$ instead of $\sum_{j=0}^i$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Ok, thanks, I'll give it a try. I tried changing the upper limit instead of the lower limit which didn't work.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Our versions that converge to 0 at the origin match almost as closely as our versions that converge to 4 at the origin: see https://i.stack.imgur.com/6esio.jpg.

Comment: Yes but for which $N$? What happens if you take very big $N$? They cannot match for $x>N$, right? I mean, if you force coincidence for all positive integers up to $N$, I expect that matching for small non-integers too will become worse for larger $N$.

Comment: Anyway I think that arXiv version deserves a separate answer. I will think more on proving its convergence rigorously.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე You're correct $\sigma(n)$ only evaluates correctly for $n\in\mathbb{Z}\land 0<|n|\le N$. I suspect you're correct on your other point as well. I'm hoping I don't run into the same problem with my analytic formula for $\mu(x)$. I was thinking of posting the formula for $\sigma(n)$ in the PDF as a separate answer (unless you beat me to it), but the PDF formula converges to $-\frac{1}{2}$ at $n=0$ which doesn't make sense. I believe the formula  for $\sigma'(n)$ derived from the PDF converges to a finite value ($\approx -3.8$) at $x=1$, but this still isn't the OP's desired value.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Perhaps my formula for $\sigma(0)$ converges to zero at non-integer values of $x$ as $N,f\to\infty$ when evaluated at $x\ll N\ll f$?

Comment: As I said, I would expect that this does not give a single value: it might give different results for, say, $f=2N$, for $f=N^2$ and for $f=2^N$. Besides, experiments somehow suggest that for $f=kN$ for any fixed $k$ the sequence stays bounded but does not tend to a single limit, rather it becomes sort of quasiperiodic or something. In any case it does not seem to converge to zero. And even if it would, that would mean that you do not get an analytic function, right? Any everywhere convergent power series is continuous, if it is constant zero outside a discrete set, it is zero everywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124725/discussion-between-steven-clark-and--).

Answer (score 2):

Since the formula I posted in my previous answer only converges as $N\to\infty$ at $x\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ne 0}$, I decided to post another formula which I believe converges as $N\to\infty$ for $x\in\mathbb{C}$. The previous answer I posted is consistent with the fact that zero has an infinite number of divisors, but this answer assumes the definition $\sigma_0(0)=0$.

---

Consider the following definitions of the analytic extension $\tilde{\sigma}_0(x)$ of $\sigma_0(n)$ and it's first order derivative $\tilde{\sigma}_0'(x)$ which are based on partial evaluations of real analytic formulas for $\tilde{f_{\sigma_0}}'(x)=\sum\limits_n \sigma_0(n)\,\delta(x-n)$ and $\tilde{f_{\sigma_0}}''(x)=\sum\limits_n \sigma_0(n)\,\delta'(x-n)$ (see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4174679) I posted to a related question on Math StackExchange).

---

$$\tilde{\sigma}_0(x)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\left(-\frac{\sin(2 \pi x)}{\pi x}+\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\left(\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi k x}{n}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi (k-1) x}{n}\right)\right)\right)\right)\tag{1}$$

$$\tilde{\sigma}_0'(x)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\left(\frac{\sin(2 \pi x)-2 \pi x \cos(2 \pi x)}{\pi x^2}-\frac{2 \pi}{n^2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\left(k \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi k x}{n}\right)+(k-1) \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi (k-1) x}{n}\right)\right)\right)\right)\tag{2}$$

---

Figure (1) below illustrates formula (1) for $\tilde{\sigma}_0(x)$ evaluated at $N=100$ in blue where the red discrete evaluation points illustrate $\sigma_0(x)$ for $x=n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (1)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula (1) for $\tilde{\sigma}_0(x)$

---

The following table illustrates formula (2) for $\tilde{\sigma}_0'(x)$ evaluated at $x=1$ seems to converge to approximately $-3.35$ as $N\to\infty$.

---

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 N & \tilde{\sigma}_0'(1) \\
 100 & -3.31334 \\
 1000 & -3.34278 \\
 10000 & -3.34574 \\
\end{array}$$