# Questions on analytic representations of the Kronecker delta function $\delta(x-1)$ and the Moebius function $\mu(n)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, dirichlet-series

This question is related to analytic formulas for $a(n)$ where $f_a(x)$ and $F_a(s)$ defined in formulas (1) and (2) below are the summatory function and Dirichlet series associated with $a(n)$.

---

$$f_a(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x a(n)\tag{1}$$

$$F_a(s)=s\int\limits_0^\infty f_a(x)\,x^{-s-1}\,dx=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a(n)\ n^{-s}\tag{2}$$

---

In the remainder of this question $\tilde{a}(x)$ is used to refer to an analytic representation of the arithmetic function $a(n)$. The analytic representation $\tilde{a}(x)$ typically converges to $a(n)$ when $|x|=n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ne 0}$, but $\tilde{a}(0)$ may or may not converge to $a(0)$ when $a(0)$ is defined and meaningful.

---

The following two analytic formulas for $\tilde{a}(x)$ are based on [An Exact Formula for the Prime Counting Function](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.09818.pdf), where the only difference between the two formulas is formula (4) starts the inner series at $j=1$ instead of $j=0$. Formulas (3) and (4) below are both indeterminate at $x=0$ (because $0^0$ is indeterminate) but they converge at $x=0$ in a limit sense. I'll note that formulas (3) and (4) are both extremely slow to converge and extremely sensitive to evaluation precision, and formula (4) generally diverges faster (at a smaller magnitude of $x$) than formula (3) when both formulas are evaluated at the same limit $I$.

---

$$\tilde{a}(x)=\underset{I\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(-2\sum\limits_{i=0}^I (-1)^i (2 \pi x)^{2 i} \sum\limits_{j=0}^i \frac{(-1)^j (2 \pi)^{-2 j} F_a(2 j)}{(2 i-2 j+1)!}\right)\tag{3}$$

$$\tilde{a}(x)=\underset{I\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(-2\sum\limits_{i=0}^I (-1)^i (2 \pi x)^{2 i} \sum\limits_{j=1}^i \frac{(-1)^j (2 \pi)^{-2 j} F_a(2 j)}{(2 i-2 j+1)!}\right)\tag{4}$$

---

I believe in some cases the analytic formula for $\tilde{a}(n)$ defined in formula (5) below may be related or equivalent to the analytic formulas defined in formulas (3) and (4) above. The analytic function $\tilde{a}(x)$ defined in formula (5) evaluates exactly to $a(n)$ when $x=n\in\mathbb{Z}\land0<|n|\le N$. When formulas (3) and (4) above converge for a particular definition of $a(n)$, there are at least two conditions related to the evaluation limit $N$ in formula (5) below that are necessary, but perhaps not sufficient, to achieve this equivalence which are discussed following formula (5) below.

---

$$\tilde{a}(x)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{b(n)}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi k x}{n}\right)\right)\quad\text{where}\quad b(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n}a(d)\,\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\tag{5}$$

---

> **Condition (1)**: The first condition necessary for formula (5) to evaluate equivalent to formula (3) or (4) is the limit defined in formula (6) below must converge, and more specifically I believe it must converge to zero. If this limit diverges, formula (4) will still evaluate exactly to $a(n)$ when $x=n\in\mathbb{Z}\land0<|n|\le N$, but will diverge at non-integer values of $x$.

---

$$\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{b(n)}{n}\right)=0\tag{6}$$

---

> **Condition (2)**: The second condition necessary for formula (5) to evaluate equivalent to formula (3) or (4) is it must be possible to evaluate $\tilde{a}(0)$ defined in formula (7) below to a particular value for arbitrarily large magnitudes of the evaluation limit $N$. This implies $\tilde{a}(0)$ defined in formula (7) below can be evaluated to this specific value for an infinite number of values of $N$.

---

$$\tilde{a}(0)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N b(n)\tag{7}$$

---

In all of the figures below, the red discrete portion of the plots represents the evaluation of the arithmetic function $a(n)$ at integer values. Formulas (3) and (4) are generally illustrated in blue (except Figure (1) which illustrates formula (4) in green) and formula (5) is always illustrated in orange.

---

In the case where $a(n)=1$, $f_a(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$, $F_a(s)=\zeta(s)$, and $b(n)=\delta_{n-1}$ (Kronecker delta). For the case $a(n)=1$, Condition (2) specified above is met with respect to the potential equivalency of formulas (3) and (5), but the limit specified in Condition (1) above converges to $1$ instead of $0$.

---

Figure (1) below illustrates for the case $a(n)=1$, formula (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ (orange) is more closely related to formula (3) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ (blue) than it is to formula (4) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ (green). In the case where $a(n)=1$, formula (3) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ corresponds to the power series for $\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2 \pi x))$, and formula (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ corresponds to $\cos(2 \pi x)$.

---

[image: Illustration of formulas (3), (4), and (5) for a(n)=1]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formulas (3), (4), and (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ (blue, green, and orange) for $a(n)=1$

---

In the simplest case where $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$ (Kronecker delta function), $f_a(x)=\theta(x-1)$, $F_a(s)=1$, and $b(n)=\mu(n)$. Note conditions (1) and (2) specified above are both met since $\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\right)=0$ and $\tilde{a}(0)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\mu(n)$ is the Mertens function $M(N)$ which evaluates to every integer an infinite number of times.

---

In the case of $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$, formulas (8) and (9) below are equivalent to formulas (3) and (4) above where $_1\tilde{F}_2()$ is the [Hypergeometric PFQ Regularized function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQRegularized/).

---

$$\tilde{\delta}_{x-1}=\underset{I\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^I (-1)^{i+1} \pi^{2 i+\frac{5}{2}} \, _1\tilde{F}_2\left(1;i+2,i+\frac{5}{2};-\pi ^2\right) x^{2 i}\right)\tag{8}$$

$$\tilde{\delta}_{x-1}=\underset{I\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^I (-1)^i \pi^{2 i+\frac{1}{2}} \, _1\tilde{F}_2\left(1;i+1,i+\frac{3}{2};-\pi ^2\right) x^{2 i}\right)\tag{9}$$

---

Figure (2) below illustrates formulas (3) and (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ (blue and orange) where $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$. Formula (3) is evaluated at $I=100$, and formula (5) is evaluated at $N=103$ which was selected to match the evaluation of formula (3) at $x=0$ which converges (in a limit sense) to $-2$. Note formula (5) evaluates so closely to formula (3) that the evaluation of formula (5) pretty much hides the underlying evaluation of formula (3).

---

[image: Illustration of formulas (3) and (5) for a(n)=delta(n-1)]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of formulas (3) and (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ (blue and orange) where $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$

---

Figure (3) below illustrates formulas (4) and (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ (blue and orange) where $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$. Formula (4) is evaluated at $I=100$, and formula (5) is evaluated at $N=101$ which was selected to achieve the correct evaluation at $x=0$. Note formula (4) also converges (in a limit sense) to the correct value at $x=0$. Note formula (5) doesn't seem to evaluate as closely to formula (4) in Figure (3) below as it did to formula (3) in Figure (2) above. I've noticed formula (4) typically diverges faster (at a smaller magnitude of $x$) than formula (3) when both are evaluated at the same limit $I$ which may be part of the reason, but it may also be that formula (5) is not as closely related to formula (4) as it is to formula (3) which was clearly the case illustrated in Figure (1) above for $a(n)=1$.

---

[image: Illustration of formulas (4) and (5) for a(n)=delta(n-1)]

**Figure (3)**: Illustration of formulas (4) and (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ (blue and orange) where $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$

---

> **Question (1)**: Assuming $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$, can it be shown that formula (5) above is exactly equivalent to formula (3) and/or formula (4) above as $I\to\infty$ and $N\to\infty$ with the additional constraint $N$ is selected such that formula (7) for $\tilde{a}(0)$ matches the evaluation of formula (3) and/or formula (4) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ at $x=0$?

---

In the case where $a(n)=\mu(n)$ (Moebius function), $f_a(x)=M(x)$ which is the Mertens function, $F_a(s)=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$, and $b(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n}\mu(d)\,\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)$. Note condition (1) specified above is met since $\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{b(n)}{n}\right)=0$ (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4153467) to my related question on Math StackExchange). The second necessary condition for equivalence of formula (5) to formulas (3) or (4) in the case of $a(n)=\mu(n)$ is it must be possible to evaluate formula (7) above for $\tilde{a}(0)$ to $4$ or $0$ for arbitrarily large magnitudes of the limit $N$. I believe this condition is met but this is still an open issue (see my [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4150078) on Math StackExchange).

---

Figure (4) below illustrates formulas (3) and (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ (blue and orange) where $a(n)=\mu(n)$. Formula (3) is evaluated at $I=100$, and formula (5) is evaluated at $N=141$ which was selected to match the evaluation of formula (3) at $x=0$ which converges (in a limit sense) to $4$. Note formula (5) evaluates so closely to formula (3) that the evaluation of formula (5) pretty much hides the underlying evaluation of formula (3).

---

[image: Illustration of formulas (3) and (5) for a(n)=mu(n)]

**Figure (4)**: Illustration of formulas (3) and (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ (blue and orange) where $a(n)=\mu(n)$

---

Figure (5) below illustrates formulas (4) and (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ (blue and orange) where $a(n)=\mu(n)$. Formula (4) is evaluated at $I=100$, and formula (5) is evaluated at $N=140$ which was selected to achieve the correct evaluation at $x=0$. Note formula (4) also converges (in a limit sense) to the correct value at $x=0$. Note formula (5) doesn't seem to evaluate as closely to formula (4) in Figure (5) below as it did to formula (3) in Figure (4) above.

---

[image: Illustration of formulas (4) and (5) for a(n)=mu(n)]

**Figure (5)**: Illustration of formulas (4) and (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ (blue and orange) where $a(n)=\mu(n)$

---

> **Question (2)**: Assuming $a(n)=\mu(n)$, can it be shown that formula (5) above is exactly equivalent to formula (3) and/or formula (4) above as $I\to\infty$ and $N\to\infty$ with the additional constraint $N$ is selected such that formula (7) for $\tilde{a}(0)$ matches the evaluation of formula (3) and/or formula (4) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ at $x=0$?

---

In the case where $a(n)=(-1)^{n-1}$, $f_a(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\text{SquareWave}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$, $F_a(s)=\eta(s)$ (Dirichlet eta function), and $b(n)=\{1,-2,0,0,0,...\}$ ($b(1)=1$, $b(2)=-2$, and $b(n)=0$ for $n>2$). For the case $a(n)=(-1)^{n-1}$, Conditions (1) and (2) specified above are both met with respect to the equivalency of formulas (3) and (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$.

---

Figure (6) below illustrates for the case $a(n)=(-1)^{n-1}$, formula (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ (orange) is exactly equivalent to formula (3) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ (blue) but much less closely related to formula (4) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ (green). In the case where $a(n)=(-1)^{n-1}$, formula (3) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ corresponds to the power series for $-cos(\pi x)$, and formula (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ also corresponds to $-\cos(\pi x)$.

---

[image: Illustration of formulas (3), (4), and (5) for a(n)=(-1)^(n-1)]

**Figure (6)**: Illustration of formulas (3), (4), and (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ (blue, green, and orange) for $a(n)=(-1)^{n-1}$

---

The discrete plot in Figure (7) below illustrates the relationship between the evaluation of the offset defined in formula (6) (orange) and the evaluation of formula (5) for $\tilde{a}(1.5)$ (blue) for the case $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$ where $b(n)=\mu(n)$ and formula (7) for $\tilde{a}(0)$ corresponds to the Mertens function $M(N)$. Both formulas are evaluated at the zeros of the Mertens function in the range $1\le N\le 10000$ corresponding to Condition (2) necessary for the equivalence of formulas (4) and (5) for $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$. There are $406$ zeros of the Merten's function in the range $1\le N\le 10000$ with the first occurring at $N=2$ and the last occuring at $N=9256$. The horizontal axis in Figure (6) below represents of the index of the Merten's function zero. Note the oscillations in the evaluation of $\tilde{a}(1.5)$ (blue) are opposite in sign but nearly equal in magnitude to the oscillations in the evaluation of the formula (6) offset (orange). Since the offset in formula (6) converges to zero as $N\to\infty$, it would seem the oscillations in the evaluation of formula (5) for $\tilde{a}(1.5)$ also converge to zero as $N\to\infty$ when $\tilde{a}(0)=M(N)=0$.

---

[image: Illustration of relationship between formula (5) for a(1.5) and the offset in formula (6)]

**Figure (7)**: Illustration of formula (5) for $\tilde{a}(1.5)$ and the offset in formula (6) as a function 0f $N$ where $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$ and the horizontal axis represents the index of $\tilde{a}(0)=M(N)=0$

---

The value $x=1.5$ was selected for Figure (7) above for a couple of reasons. First, formula (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ evaluates exactly correct when $x=n\in\mathbb{Z}\land0<|n|\le N$, so it seemed to me $\tilde{a}(x)$ would vary more halfway between integer values than it does when evaluated closer to integer values. Second, formula (5) for $\tilde{a}(1.5)$ and the offset corresponding to formula (6) both evaluate close to zero as $N$ increases which allows the plot range to be magnified when both functions are combined on the same plot thereby providing visibility into the finer details. The magnified plot range illustrated in Figure (7) above truncated some of the earlier evaluation points corresponding to smaller values of $N$ where formula (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ and the offset defined in formula (6) evaluated to larger magnitudes before they started to exhibit better convergence.

Comment: Seems like your (5) diverges for any non-integer $x$ for Kronecker delta and for $\mu$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Perhaps it may seem that way for magnitudes of $N$ that can be practically evaluated, but I believe it converges as $N\to\infty$ since the offset $\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{b(n)}{n}\right)=0$ for $b(n)=\mu(n)$ and $b(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n}\mu(d)\,\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)$. Try plotting the offset $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{b(n)}{n}$ and you'll see it bounces around for small magnitudes of $N$ which is perhaps misleading you.

Comment: I am just taking sequences of your (5) for $N=1,2,3,...,500$ for various fixed $x$ like $x=1.001$ or $x=2.999$; the values always oscillate with increasing amplitude.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე You're ignoring condition (2). First you must select $N$ such that condition (2) is met. But even if you just look at values of $N$ that meet condition (2), I expect the evaluation at non-integer values of $x$ to bounce around a bit since the offset defined in formula (6) bounces around a bit. I believe this oscillation decreases in amplitude as $N\to\infty$ since formula (6) converges to zero as $N\to\infty$, but it may not be practical to evaluate formula (6) at large enough magnitudes of $N$ to convince yourself.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. There is no $N$ in (2).

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Perhaps you're looking at formula (2)? Condition (2) is formula (7) where $N$ is the evaluation limit.

Comment: Oh I see sorry. So does it hold for $\mu$ or $\delta$? And how does it help? You need the limit, if the partial sum attains (even for any other fixed $x$, not just zero) the correct value for infinitely many $N$, you still cannot stop since until you pass to the limit, infinitely many values at (large) integers will be wrong, no? And it might happen that the limit simply does not exist.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The limit in formula (6) associated with condition (1) is met for both $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$ and $a(n)=\mu(n)$, and condition (2) is also met for $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$ since in this case $\tilde{a}(0)$ defined in formula (7) corresponds to the Mertens function $M(N)$ which can be evaluated to any integer at an infinite number of values of $N$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე In the case of $a(n)=\mu(n)$, if it turns out $\tilde{a}(0)$ defined in formula (7) can only be evaluated to $4$ or $1$ as it was in Figures (4) and (5) for a finite number of values of $N$, then formula (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ doesn't converge for the case $a(n)=\mu(n)$ since there are no values of $N$ for which formula (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ can be evaluated correctly both at $x=0$ and at an arbitrarily large integer value of $x$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე A proof of convergence of formula (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ for the case $a(n)=\mu(n)$ requires a proof that condition (2) is met, and it may turn out condition (2) is not met. This motivated me to include the simpler case $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$ where condition (2) is met as well as condition (1).

Comment: Seems to diverge for $\delta$ too. Actually I do not understand why your condition (2) is necessary. If, say, the sum of $b(n)$ converges, you do have a definite value for $\tilde a(0)$ while condition (2) might be violated. On the other hand it might happen that condition (2) holds but the sum of $b(n)$ does not converge, which means that $\tilde a(0)$ is undefined. So if that sum does not converge then it is not clear whether the function defined by (5) is analytic at 0, and you need some other means to ensure its analyticity there.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I'm working on a plot that illustrates why I believe formula (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ converges when conditions (1) and (2) are met. In the mean time, here are a couple of interesting observations.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე For the case $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$, when $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\zeta (s)}$ is evaluated at $s=0$, the left-hand side corresponds to formula (7) for $\tilde{a}(0)$ and the right-hand side corresponds to $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=-2$ which is consistent with Figure (2).

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე For the case $a(n)=\mu(n)$, when $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{b(n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\zeta (s)^2}$ is evaluated at $s=0$, the left-hand side once again corresponds to formula (7) for $\tilde{a}(0)$ and in this case the right-hand side corresponds to $\frac{1}{\zeta(0)^2}=4$ which is consistent with Figure (4).

Comment: Of course for $N$ with the partial sum at 0 equal to what I want you will get at 0 what you want. But I doubt you can obtain any definite value in a neighborhood of 0 except at 0 itself. And in any case you cannot stop at any $N$ since you need agreement with $a(n)$ for *all* $n$, so I don't see any point in considering these partial sums. It can also happen that for some subsequences of $N$ satisfying (2) you get some limiting values at some points, and these values can be different for different subsequences.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I added Figure (7) and a couple of paragraphs to illustrate why I believe formula (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ converges as $N\to\infty$. I don't really understand your point. There are many functions which can only be approximated by partial sums of an infinite series, and it's not unusual to have to increase the evaluation limit $N$ as the magnitude of $x$ increases. You can't just stop at a finite value of $N$ and expect series like those defined in formulas (3), (4), and (5) above to converge for all values of $x$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე When I evaluate formula (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ for the case $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$ at non-integer values like $x=0.001$, $x=1.001$, and $x=2.999$ in plots analogous to the evaluation at $x=1.5$ illustrated in Figure (7) above, I get virtually no variation in the evaluation result which is why I selected $x=1.5$ for Figure (7) above. So I don't understand why you claim formula (5) doesn't converge when evaluated in the proximity of integer values of $x$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე For example, here's a plot analogous to Figure (7) for the case $x=2.999$: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPBjV.jpg. Note $\tilde{a}(2.999)$ seems to evaluate to almost a constant as a function of increasing magnitudes of $N$ where $\tilde{a}(0)=M(N)=0$.

Comment: I think for such cases one must look further. I did run it until $N$ about 380000 or so, and I think the picture does not suggest that the oscillations eventually will settle down. For $\delta$, the subsequence of those $N$ satisfying $\sum_{n\leqslant N}b(n)=0$ goes like $2,39,40,58,65,93,...,385111,385112,385139,385140,...$; looking at the plot of the partial sums for these $N$ https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGi7S.png I don't think one can say with confidence that there will be definite limit, no?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე What value of $x$ did you use in your last plot? I know the oscillation in $\tilde{a}(x)$ associated with the oscillation in the offset converges to zero as $N\to\infty$ because the offset itself converges to zero as $N\to\infty$ (which is equivalent to the PNT). But it's possible there are other factors contributing to the oscillation in $\tilde{a}(x)$, and it's also possible formulas (3) and (4) don't converge for the cases $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$ and/or $a(n)=\mu(n)$. Have you investigated the convergence of formulas (3) and (4) at a specific value of $x$ as $N\to\infty$?

Comment: The same value as you, $2.999$. In the meanwhile I reached 433180, looks more or less the same. Still, here it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2gWz.png. I guess the problem is that there are larger and larger gaps between the consecutive $N$  satisfying your condition 2 (I still do not see why it might be necessary). At each such gap the partial sums jump significantly; on my plots these are the straight line segments. As for (3) and (4) they seem to converge always. In fact in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3493770/214353 @reuns claims to have a proof that these are indeed entire functions.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Actually the question and comments posted by reuns imply some of the formulas in the PDF don't converge. Note reuns derived a different formula for $\mu(n)$, and note his comment: The pdf is sloppy/wrong, that's why my post starts with "in order to repair". This is actually why I asked if you had investigated convergence of the PDF formulas.

Comment: In subsequent comments (s?)he claims that the same proof works also for the functions from that preprint.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I think reuns is saying that the analytic formula for $\tilde{\mu}(x)$ can be generalized as follows: $\tilde{a}(x)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(-2\sum\limits_{k=2}^K x^k \sum\limits_{m=1}^{\frac{k}{2}-1}\frac{(2 i \pi )^{k-2 m-2}\,F_a(2 m+2) }{(k-2 m-1)!}\right)$. But I don't see how this relates to the PDF formulas. This formula generally evaluates to a complex result for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ except at the integers, whereas the PDF formulas evaluate to a strictly real result for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It is closely related. Both entire functions can be obtained from the series $f(x)=\sum\frac{a_n/n^2}{1-x^2/n^2}$ (which only has limited radius of convergence). In the question $f(x)$ is multiplied by $\frac{1-e^{2\pi i x}}{2\pi i}$ while to obtain series from the preprint you multiply $f(x)$ by $\frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{2\pi}$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The PDF formula has closed-form expressions for the cases $a(n)=1$ and $a(n)=(-1)^{n-1}$ associated with $\zeta(s)$ and $\eta(s)$ which are $\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2 \pi x))$ and $-cos(\pi x)$. I'm wondering if the formula posted by reuns also has closed-form expressions for the cases $a(n)=1$ and $a(n)=(-1)^{n-1}$.

Comment: Yes, the coefficients sum up to $\frac{(2 \pi  i)^k (k-1)}{2 (k+1)!}$ for $\zeta$ and to $\frac{(2 \pi  i)^k \left(2^k-k-1\right)}{2^k (k+1)!}$ for $\eta$; accordingly, the series gives $1+\frac{\left(1-e^{2 i \pi  x}\right) (1-i \pi  x)}{2 \pi  i x}$ for $\zeta$ and $-\frac{1-e^{2 i \pi  x}}{2 \pi  i x}-e^{i \pi  x}$ for $\eta$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Thanks. In the generalized formula I posted in a comment above I started the inner series at $m=1$ (which reuns didn't specify). I see you started the inner sum at $m=0$ instead of $m=1$ which I was also investigating because I noticed it seemed to be more closely related to the PDF formula when it's inner series is started at $j=1$ instead of $j=0$, and $j=1$ gives the correct evaluation of $a(0)$.

Comment: Yes, I had in mind analog of (3). It should be easy to derive the analog of (4) too

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Did you see the answer I posted to reuns related question on Math StackExchange at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4160465? Also, for some definitions of $a(n)$ (e.g. $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$ and $a(n)=\mu(n)$) formula (3) above seems to evaluate similar the real part of the generalization of reuns formula I posted in a comment above when the inner sum is started at $m=-1$ instead of $m=1$ except there seems to be an offset related to $a(n)$ (and perhaps the evaluation limit).

Comment: Well, frankly speaking I strongly doubt that @reuns will accept this answer - the question was about anything essential from that preprint that has not been addressed.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I don't expect reuns to accept the answer, but I provided information related to his formula that perhaps might be of interest to others. The question by reuns was soliciting feedback from the author of the PDF whose account has been terminated.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The answer I posted below illustrates that reuns as well as the author of the paper really only understood the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: There are zillions of entire functions with prescribed values at integers. Among them, the ones given by particular series indicated in that preprint by Risomar Sousa seem to have interesting connection to number theory. I don't see anything significant going on beyond that. In particular, all of your sums require specifying a particular summation method, otherwise it is completely unclear which globally defined *function* do you mean by them. Different summations might converge to different functions, and so far I don't even see whether any of them provide any well-defined function at all.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I recommend you just ignore my original formulas and their conjectured relationship with the formulas in the PDF and focus on formulas (f) and (g) in the answer I posted below. Whereas my original formulas (d) and (e) in my answer below require evaluation at specific values of N (which you're not comfortable with), the corresponding formulas (f) and (g) in my answer below eliminate this requirement.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე But formula (4) in my answer above is simply formula (g) in my answer below normalized by $\frac{1}{2f}$ and then evaluated at $f=1$, just as formula (5) in my answer above was simply formula (e) in my answer below normalized by $\frac{1}{2f}$ and then evaluated at $f=1$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე By the way, reuns provided a proof of formula (e) in my answer below for the case $a(n)=\delta_{x-1}$ where $b(n)=\mu(n)$ and $\tilde{f}_a'(x)=\delta(x+1)+\delta(x-1)$ in the answer posted to my Math Overflow question at https://mathoverflow.net/q/362566. Formulas (e) and (g) in my answer below only converge in a distributional sense, and I'm not sure what that implies about convergence of either formula when evaluated at the finite limit $f=1$ associated with the question above.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე For the case $a(n)=1$ associated with $F_a(s)=\zeta(s)$, I believe the analytic formula for $\tilde{f}_a'(x)$ defined in formula (g) in my answer below has the closed form representation $\tilde{f}_a'(x)=1+\cos(2 \pi x)-\frac{\sin(2 \pi x)}{\pi x}$ when evaluated at $f=1$. Do you have any insight on how to generalize this closed form representation to all positive integer values of $f$ for the case $a(n)=1$ associated with $F_a(s)=\zeta(s)$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand these (f) and (g) at all. It seems the sum converges for each fixed $f$ but goes to infinity as $f$ increases. Why do you include this $f$? With $f=1$ this is very similar to the series by Risomar Sousa but for large $f$ seems to be unbounded. And in what sense could they be equivalent to (d) and (e) I also don't understand at all.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Formulas (e) and (g) for $\tilde{f}_a'(x)$ in my answer below diverge to $\infty$ as $f\to\infty$ when $x=n\in\mathbb{Z}\land a(n)\ne 0$ because they're analytic representations which converge in a distributional sense to $f_a'(x)=\sum\limits_n a(n)\,\delta(x-n)$ where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function. Are you not familiar with the Fourier series for the Dirac comb? Try evaluating formulas (d) and (f) for $\tilde{f}_a(x)$ and you'll see they converge to $f_a(x)=\sum\limits_n a(n)\,\theta(x-n)$ where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე But beware when evaluating formula (f) each time you increase the evaluation frequency $f$ while holding $K$ constant you decrease the range of convergence over $x$. For example, if formula (f) diverges for $|x|>12$ when evaluated at $f=1$, it will diverge for $|x|>6$ when evaluated at $f=2$, and it will diverge for $|x|>4$ when evaluated at $f=3$ (assuming all three evaluation frequencies are evaluated with the same value of $K$).

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The exact equivalence of formulas (4) and (5) for $\tilde{a}(x)$ in my question above at non-integer values of $x$ is no longer as important to me now that I understand the higher-level context revealed in formulas (f) and (g) in my answer below.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Formulas (d) and (e) in my answer below have already been proven for the case $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$ where $b(n)=\mu(n)$ and $\tilde{f}_a'(x)=\delta(x+1)+\delta(x-1)$. I think what's important going forward is a proof of the validity of formulas (f) and (g) in my answer below for all definitions of $a(n)$ for which $F_a(s)=\sum\limits_n a(n)\,n^{-s}$ converges for $\Re(s)\ge 2$.

Comment: Actually I now looked at the $\delta$ case for a specific $x=2.01$, and, unless I am doing something wrong, the limit in (f) is $\infty$ no matter how I increase $f$ and $K$. As for (d) and (e), sorry, I don't see how they have been proven.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I'm not sure what you're doing. Here's a plot of formula (f) for $\tilde{f}_a(x)$ for the case of $a(n)=\delta_{x-1}$ where formula (f) is evaluated at $f=2$ and $K=200$: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ggFE.jpg. Formula (f) is shown in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $f(x)=-1+\theta(x+1)+\theta(x-1)$. Are you sure you have formula (f) entered correctly?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე For the case $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$ you should be using $F_a(s)=1$, and note there's an extra $x$ in the numerator in formula (f) in my answer below.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე For the case $\delta_{x-1}$ I can only get get formula (f) for $\tilde{f}_a(x)$ to converge at $x=2.01$ for $f\in\{1,2,3\}$ which I suspect is related to the fact that I can only get it to converge at $f=1$ for $|x|<~4.5$. As I said before, the convergence range decreases each time you increase the value of $f$, but the decrease in the convergence range is not quite as linear as I originally indicated.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე For the cases $a(n)=1$ and $a(n)=(-1)^{n-1}$ where $F_a(s)=\zeta(s)$ and $F_a(s)=\eta(s)$, I suspect it would be easier to illustrate convergence over much larger ranges of $f$ and $x$ if we could come up with generalized closed form representations of formula (g) for $\tilde{f}_a'(x)$ which then could be integrated to derive generalized closed form representations of formula (f) for $\tilde{f}_a(x)$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  I believe the closed form representations of formula (g) for $\tilde{f}_a'(x)$ related to $\zeta(s)$ and $\eta(s)$ at $f=1$ are $\tilde{f}_a'(x)=1+\cos(2 \pi x)-\frac{\sin(2 \pi x)}{\pi x}$ and $\tilde{f}_a'(x)=\frac{\sin (2 \pi  x)}{\pi x}-2\cos (\pi x)$. Can we generalize these closed form representations as a function of the evaluation frequency $f$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე With respect to your comment "As for (d) and (e), sorry, I don't see how they have been proven", I only said they were proven for the case $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$ where $b(n)=\mu(n)$, $\tilde{f}_a'(x)=\delta(x+1)+\delta(x-1)$, and $\tilde{f}_a(x)=-1+\theta(x+1)+\theta(x-1)$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Were you not  satisfied with the proof of $\tilde{f}_a'(x)=\underset{N\to\infty,\,M(N)=0}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k x}{n}\right)\right)=\delta(x+1)+\delta(x-1)$ at https://mathoverflow.net/q/362566 which also implies $\tilde{f}_a(x)=\underset{N\to\infty,\,M(N)=0}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\mu(n)\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k x}{n}\right)}{k}\right)=-1+\theta(x+1)+\theta(x-1)$?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The function $f_a(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}a(n)$ defined in formula (1) in the question above can also be evaluated as defined in formula (a) below which leads to the analytic representations of $\tilde{f}_a(x)=\underset{\epsilon\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{f_a(x-\epsilon)+f_a(x+\epsilon)}{2}$ and it's first order derivative $\tilde{f}_a'(x)$ defined in formulas (b) and (c) below where the evaluation frequency $f$ is assumed to be a positive integer.

---

$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x a(n)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x b(n)\ \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\right\rfloor\quad\text{where}\quad b(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n}a(d)\,\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\tag{a}$$

$$\tilde{f}_a(x)=\underset{N,f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N b(n)\left(\frac{x}{n}-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{f\,n}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2 \pi k x}{n}\right)}{k}\right)\right)\right),\quad x>0\tag{b}$$

$$\tilde{f}_a'(x)=\underset{N,f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{b(n)}{n}\left(1+2\sum\limits_{k=1}^{f\,n}\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi k x}{n}\right)\right)\right),\quad x>0\tag{c}$$

---

Formulas (b) and (c) above correspond to analytic representations of $f(x)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a(n)\,\theta(x-n)\right)$ and $f'(x)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a(n)\,\delta(x-n)\right)$ where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function and $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function.

---

When conditions (1) and (2) defined in the question above are met formulas (b) and (c) above can be simplified to formulas (d) and (e) below. The function $\tilde{f}_a'(x)$ defined in formula (e) below evaluates exactly to $2\,f\, a(n)$ when $x=n\in\mathbb{Z}\land0<|n|\le N$ which leads to the analytic formula for $\tilde{a}(x)$ defined in formula (5) in the question above. Formula (5) in the question above is simply formula (e) below multiplied by the normalization factor $\frac{1}{2\,f}$ and then evaluated at $f=1$.

---

$$\tilde{f}_a(x)=\underset{N,f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N b(n)\sum\limits_{k=1}^{f\,n}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2 \pi k x}{n}\right)}{k}\right),\quad x>0\tag{d}$$

$$\tilde{f}_a'(x)=\underset{N,f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(2\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{b(n)}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{f\,n}\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi k x}{n}\right)\right),\quad x>0\tag{e}$$

---

I've discovered the relationship between formula (4) in the question above and formula (e) above is deeper than I originally anticipated. I believe the following two analytic formulas for $\tilde{f}_a(x)$ and $\tilde{f}_a'(x)$ are valid when conditions (1) and (2) in the question above are met where once again the evaluation frequency $f$ is assumed to be a positive integer.

---

$$\tilde{f}_a(x)=\underset{\substack{K,f\to\infty \\ K\gg f\,x}}{\text{lim}}\left(-4 f \sum\limits_{k=1}^K \frac{(-1)^k\ x^{2 k+1}}{2 k+1} \sum\limits_{j=1}^k \frac{(-1)^j\ (2 \pi f)^{2(k-j)}\ F_a(2 j)}{(2 k-2 j+1)!}\right)\tag{f}$$

$$\tilde{f}_a'(x)=\underset{\substack{K,f\to\infty \\ K\gg f\,x}}{\text{lim}}\left(-4 f\sum\limits_{k=1}^K (-1)^k\ x^{2 k}\sum\limits_{j=1}^k \frac{(-1)^j\ (2 \pi f)^{2(k-j)}\ F_a(2 j)}{(2 k-2 j+1)!}\right)\tag{g}$$

---

When conditions (1) and (2) defined in the question above are met, I believe formulas (f) and (g) above are equivalent to formulas (d) and (e) above. When condition (1) is met but condition (2) is not met, I originally anticipated formulas (f) and (g) would still be valid even though formulas (d) and (e) above are no longer valid. When condition (1) is not met, I originally suspected additional terms might need to be added to formulas (f) and (g) to make them valid. But to my surprise formulas (f) and (g) above seem to evaluate correctly for every definition of $a(n)$ I've tested, but I'll note these evaluations were over very small ranges of $x$ using very small evaluation limits.

---

I've tested formulas (f) and (g) above for the function $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$ where conditions (1) and (2) are met, and also for the function $a(n)=\mu(n)$ where condition (1) is met and I suspect condition (2) is also met. Formulas (f) and (g) seem to evaluate correctly for both of these cases. For $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$, the functions $\tilde{f}(x)$ and $\tilde{f}'(x)$ correspond to analytic representations of $-1+\theta(x+1)+\theta(x-1)$ and $\delta(x+1)+\delta(x-1)$. For the case $a(n)=\mu(n)$, the functions $\tilde{f}(x)$ and $\tilde{f}'(x)$ correspond to analytic representations of the Mertens function $M(x)$ and it's first-order derivative.

---

I've tested formulas (f) and (g) above for the function $a(n)=1$ associated with the Dirichlet series for $\zeta(s)$. In this case, formula (f) above for $\tilde{f}(x)$ seems to evaluate correctly, and formula (g) above for $\tilde{f}'(x)$ seems to evaluate to a Dirac comb with a tooth missing at $x=0$. This seems to suggest the following analytic formulas for $\theta(x)$ and $\delta(x)$ where the functions $\tilde{f}_a(x)$ and $\tilde{f}_a'(x)$ referenced in formulas (h) and (i) below are defined in formulas (f) and (g) above and are assumed to be evaluated with $F_a(s)=\zeta(s)$ and with the same evaluation frequency $f$ used to evaluate formulas (h) and (i) below.

---

$$\theta(x)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum\limits_{k=1}^f \frac{\sin(2 \pi k x)}{k}-\left(\tilde{f}_a(x)-x\right)\right)\tag{h}$$

$$\delta(x)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(2\sum\limits_{k=1}^f \cos(2 \pi k x)-\left(\tilde{f}_a'(x)-1\right)\right)\tag{i}$$

---

Figures (1) and (2) below illustrate formulas (h) and (i) for $\theta(x)$ and $\delta(x)$ above both seem to evaluate pretty much as expected where both formulas were evaluated with $f=4$ and $K=200$.

---

[image: Illustration of Formula (h) for theta(x)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of Formula (h) for $\theta(x)$ evaluated at $f=4$ and $K=200$

---

[image: Illustration of Formula (i) for delta(x)]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of Formula (i) for $\delta(x)$ evaluated at $f=4$ and $K=200$

---

I've also tested formulas (f) and (g) above for the function $a(n)=(-1)^{n-1}$ associated with the Dirichlet series for $\eta(s)$. In this case, formula (f) above for $\tilde{f}(x)$ seems to evaluate correctly, and formula (g) above for $\tilde{f}'(x)$ seems to evaluate to the sum of two Dirac combs where one of them has a tooth missing at $x=0$.

---

I've also tested formulas (f) and (g) above for the functions $a(n)=\lambda(n)$, $a(n)=\sigma_0(n)$, $a(n)=\Lambda(n)$, and $a(n)=\frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n}$ associated with the Dirichlet series for $\frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)}$, $\zeta(s)^2$, $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$, and $\log\zeta(s)$, and to my surprise both formulas seem to evaluate correctly for these cases as well.

---

Assuming the function $G_a(s)$ defined in formula (j) below converges, it can perhaps be used to derive formulas for functions like $F_a(s)=\zeta(s)$ and $F_a(s)=\frac{\zeta'(x)}{\zeta(s)}$ associated with $a(n)=1$ and $a(n)=\Lambda(n)$ from relationships like those illustrated in formulas (k) and (l) below.

---

$$G_a(s)=s\int\limits_1^\infty\tilde{f}(x)\,x^{-s-1}\,dx=\underset{\substack{K,f\to\infty \\ K\gg f\,x}}{\text{lim}}\left(-4 f \sum\limits_{k=1}^K \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)}\frac{s}{(s-2 k-1)}\sum\limits_{j=1}^k \frac{(-1)^j\ (2 \pi f)^{2(k-j)}\ F_a(2 j)}{(2 k-2 j+1)!}\right)\tag{j}$$

---

$$\zeta(s)=\frac{s}{s-1}+s\int_1^\infty (\lfloor x\rfloor-x)\ x^{-s-1}\ dx\,,\quad\Re(s)>0\tag{k}$$

$$\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\frac{s}{1-s}-s\int_1^\infty (\psi(x)-x)\ x^{-s-1}\ dx\,,\quad\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}\quad\text{(assuming RH)}\tag{l}$$

---

The following figures illustrate formula (f) for $\tilde{f}_a(x)$ above for a variety of arithmetic functions in an attempt to lend some credence to the validity of formulas (f) and (g) above. In each figure below, the reference function is illustrated in blue and formula (f) for $\tilde{f}_a(x)$ is illustrated in orange, green, and red corresponding to the evaluation frequencies $f=1$, $f=2$, and $f=3$ respectively. The red discrete evaluation points at integer values of $x$ in the figures below represent the evaluation of $f_{a_o}(x)=\frac{1}{2}(f_a(x-\epsilon)+f_a(x-\epsilon))$. The evaluation limit $K=100$ was used in all figures below.

---

All figures below share a few common characteristics. First, note that in all cases the evaluation at $f=1$ (shown in orange) seems to converge to $f_{a_o}(x)$ at integer values of $x$. Second, note that in all cases increasing the evaluation frequency decreases the range of convergence with respect to $x$, but improves the fidelity of the approximation to $f_{a_o}(x)$ before the evaluation starts to diverge. The evaluation of each frequency was terminated slightly after it started to diverge in the figures below to prevent it from corrupting the rest of the plot range.

---

[image: Illustration of Floor(x)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of $f_a(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$ where $F_a(s)=\zeta(s)$

---

[image: Illustration of fa(x) associated with eta(s)]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of $f_a(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}(-1)^{n-1}$ where $F_a(s)=\eta(s)$

---

[image: Illustration of theta(x-1)]

**Figure (3)**: Illustration of $f_a(x)=\theta(x-1)$ where $F_a(s)=1$

---

[image: Illustration of M(x)]

**Figure (4)**: Illustration of $f_a(x)=M(x)$ ([Mertens function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function)) where $F_a(s)=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$

---

[image: Illustration of D(x)]

**Figure (5)**: Illustration of $f_a(x)=D(x)$ ([divisor summatory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function)) where $F_a(s)=\zeta(s)^2$

---

[image: Illustration of L(x)]

**Figure (6)**: Illustration of $f_a(x)=L(x)$ ([summatory Liouville function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function)) where $F_a(s)=\frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)}$

---

[image: Illustration of psi(x)]

**Figure (7)**: Illustration of $f_a(x)=\psi(x)$ ([second Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function)) where $F_a(s)=\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$

---

[image: Illustration of Pi(x)]

**Figure (8)**: Illustration of $f_a(x)=\Pi(x)$ ([Riemann prime counting function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannPrimeCountingFunction.html)) where $F_a(s)=\log\zeta(s)$

---

For the cases $a(n)=1$, $a(n)=(-1)^{n-1}$ and $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$ where $F_a(s)=\zeta(s)$, $F_a(s)=\eta(s)$, and $F_a(s)=1$, I've determined formulas (f) and (g) above are simply the power series for the functions defined in formulas (m) to (r) below. This proves the validity of formulas (f) and (g) above for these particular cases, but I believe formulas (f) and (g) are more generally applicable to any definition of $a(n)$ for which the Dirichlet series $F_a(s)=\sum\limits_n\frac{a(n)}{n^s}$ converges for $\Re(s)\ge 2$. All formulas below are for $x\ge 0$, but $\tilde{f}_a'(x)$ and $\tilde{f}_a(x)$ are actually even and odd functions respectively.

---

$\quad a(n)=1 \text{ where } F_a(s)=\zeta(s)$:

$$\tilde{f}_a'(x)=\sum\limits_n\delta(x-n)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(-\frac{\sin (2 f \pi x)}{\pi  x}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^f (\cos(2 n \pi x)+\cos(2 (n-1) \pi x))\right)\tag{m}$$

$$\tilde{f}_a(x)=\sum\limits_n\theta(x-n)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(-\frac{\text{Si}(2 f \pi x)}{\pi}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^f \left(\frac{\sin(2 n \pi x)}{2 n \pi}+x\ \text{sinc}(2 (n-1) \pi x)\right)\right)\tag{n}$$

---

$\quad a(n)=(-1)^{n-1} \text{ where } F_a(s)=\eta(s)$:

$$\tilde{f}_a'(x)=\sum\limits_n (-1)^{n-1}\delta(x-n)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{\sin(2 f \pi x)}{\pi x}-2 \sum\limits_{n=1}^f \cos((2 n-1) \pi x)\right)\tag{o}$$

$$\tilde{f}_a(x)=\sum\limits_n (-1)^{n-1}\theta(x-n)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{\text{Si}(2 f \pi x)}{\pi }-\frac{2}{\pi}\sum\limits _{n=1}^f \frac{\sin ((2 n-1) \pi  x)}{2 n-1}\right)\tag{p}$$

---

$\quad a(n)=\delta_{n-1} \text{ where } F_a(s)=1$:

$$\tilde{f}_a'(x)=\delta(x-1)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{\sin(2 f \pi (x+1))}{\pi  (x+1)}+\frac{\sin(2 f \pi (x-1))}{\pi (x-1)}\right)\tag{q}$$

$$\tilde{f}_a(x)=\theta(x-1)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{\text{Si}(2 f \pi (x+1))+\text{Si}(2 f \pi (x-1))}{\pi }\right)\tag{r}$$

---

Formulas (m) to (p) above lead to the following formulas for the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ and Dirichlet eta function $\eta(s)$. Formula (s) and (t) for $\zeta(s)$ and $\eta(s)$ can also be used to derive formulas for $\zeta(s)$ and $\eta(s)$ which converge for $\Re(s)>-1$.

---

$$\zeta(s)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) \Gamma(1-s) \left(-\frac{f^s}{s}+\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sum\limits_{n=2}^f \left(n^{s-1}+(n-1)^{s-1}\right)\right)\right)\right),\ \Re(s)<2\tag{s}$$

$$\eta(s)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(2 \pi^{s-1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\ \Gamma(1-s) \left(\frac{2^{s-1} f^s}{s}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^f (2 n-1)^{s-1}\right)\right),\ \Re(s)<2\tag{t}$$

---

Formulas (n), (p), (r), and (t) above are illustrated in this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/395266) I recently posted to my own question on MathOverflow.

Comment: I don't understand, I get entirely different results. Could we please check, for $F_a(s)\equiv1$ I get the following series:$$-\frac{4 f}{3} x^3+\left(-\frac{4 f}{5}+\frac{8 \pi ^2 f^3}{15}\right) x^5+\left(-\frac{4 f}{7}+\frac{8 \pi ^2 f^3}{21}-\frac{8\pi ^4 f^5}{105} \right) x^7+\left(-\frac{4 f}{9}+\frac{8 \pi ^2 f^3}{27}-\frac{8 \pi ^4 f^5}{135}+\frac{16 \pi ^6 f^7}{2835}\right) x^9+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Your terms seem to exactly match formula (f) for $\tilde{f}(x)$ above for the case $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$ where $b(n)=\mu(n)$ and $F_a(s)=1$. What is it that you don't understand, and why do you think you get entirely different results?

Comment: Because when I increase $f$ each of these coefficients goes to infinity. If you have a procedure to obtain a finite limit somehow, it cannot be described as just $K,f\to\infty$, this will just give you infinity for all $x$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I don't believe you can base convergence on a single coefficient, rather I believe you have to consider what the entire series is doing. You may be right, but I'll have to think about it some more. I appreciate you're feedback and the time you've invested in investigating my question and answer.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The coefficients for $k=4$ can be rewritten as $-\frac{4 f}{9}\left(1-\frac{2 \pi^2 f^2}{3}+\frac{2 \pi^4 f^4}{15}-\frac{4 \pi^6 f^6}{315}\right)$ which I believe generalizes to $-\frac{4\, f}{2\,k+1}\left(1-\frac{2 \pi^2 f^2}{3}+\frac{2 \pi^4 f^4}{15}-\frac{4 \pi^6 f^6}{315}+...\right)$ and note the denominators inside of the parenthesis $\{1,3,15,315,2835,155925,6081075,638512875,10854718875,1856156927625,\text{...}\}$ correspond to https://oeis.org/A036279 which are the denominators in the Taylor series for $\tan(x)$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Correction: The denominators seem to match https://oeis.org/A156769 which resembles A036279 with the first difference occurring at a(12).

Comment: Still, each coefficient is a polynomial in $f$, so if you just increase both $K$ and $f$ independently you will always get infinity. In more detail: for each $x$ you have the numbers $S_{K,f}(x)$ (truncating the sum at $K$ for $f$). If you fix $K$ and increase $f$ you get infinity. If you fix $f$ and increase $K$ you get certain finite limit $S_f(x)$. These tend to infinity as $f$ increases. So you need something else to get a finite limit. What is it?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Since the convergence range over $x$ seems to decrease each time $f$ increases, it seems to me formulas (f) and (g) need to be evaluated such that $K\gg f\,x$. I believe a generalized closed form expression as a function of $f$ for one of the cases $a(n)=1$, $a(n)=(-1)^{n-1}$, or even $a(n)=\delta_{n-1}$ would perhaps lead to a proof or disproof for the specific case where the closed form expression can be derived.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე And if the closed form expression leads to a proof of formulas (f) and (g) for the case $a(n)=1$ or $a(n)=(-1)^{n-1}$, then it could perhaps lead to a new formula for $\zeta(s)$ or $\eta(s)$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Figures (1) to (4) in my new question on closed form representations at https://mathoverflow.net/q/395112 and Figures (5) to (8) in my updated answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4160465 are perhaps the best illustrations to date of why I believe formulas (f) and (g) in my answer above are valid.

Comment: But how do you know what will happen to these graphs when, say, $f$ is one million? Because you do need arbitrarily large $f$, right? For each such $f$ you will get a convergent series, i. e. will obtain definite limit as $K\to\infty$, but at each given $x$ this limit will be bigger and bigger as $f$ gets bigger.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I believe what you say is true which is why I modified the limits in formulas (f), (g), and (j) above to specify $K\gg f\,x$. It's not unusual for a series evaluation to require $K\gg x$, but I understand you're uncomfortable with extending it to $K\gg f\,x$. I suspect the only way to prove (or disprove) formulas (f) and (g) above is to derive a generalized closed form representation as a function of the evaluation frequency $f$. Hopefully someone will come up with an answer to my new question on this topic.

Comment: I think what I said subsumes your $K\gg fx$ condition and is actually much stronger. I propose to fix $f$ and take the limit $K\to\infty$ for this fixed $f$. For each fixed $f$ you will indeed obtain a well-defined analytic function of $x$. The problem is that, I believe, these functions will attain bigger and bigger values when you will increase $f$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე When $x=n\in\mathbb{Z}$ formula (g) for $\tilde{f}_a'(x)$ should converge to $2\,f\,a(n)$ as $K\to\infty$, so yes formula (g) for $\tilde{f}_a'(x)$ goes to infinity as $f\to\infty$ when $x=n\in\mathbb{Z}\land a(n)\ne 0$, but this is consistent with the convergence of the Fourier series for the Dirac comb of period $1$ at integer values of $x$ (which corresponds to $a(n)=1$).

Comment: I don't know about that, I just want to say that I don't see how your display (f) can define anything that does not go to infinity everywhere.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I'm not sure why you think formula (f) for $\tilde{f}_a(x)$ will converge to larger magnitudes as the magnitude of $f$ increases. The figures in my new question and updated answer illustrate formula (f) for $\tilde{f}_a(x)$ converges closer and closer to the reference function $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x} a(n)$ as the evaluation frequency $f$ increases for $1\le f\le 4$ when $x$ is within the convergence range of formula (f) for $\tilde{f}_a(x)$.

Comment: Well, I see it from the coefficients which are polynomials of increasing degrees in $f$, and also I saw it experimentally in some cases. I will show them to you, and I will also think about proving it.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Ok, thanks. I think it would help me to see your point if you could quantify how the evaluation increases as the evaluation frequency $f$ increases and explain how this quantification is consistent with the evaluations of formula (f) for $\tilde{f}_a(x)$ that I illustrated in Figures (1) to (4) of my new question at https://mathoverflow.net/q/395112 and Figures (5) to (8) of my updated answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4160465.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  For proofs of the validity of formulas (f) and (g), please see the answer I posted at https://mathoverflow.net/q/395266 to my more recent question on closed form expressions..

Comment: Yes I see now, and confirm the convergence. Except still the result is only real-analytic, I could not use it for complex $x$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The summatory function $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x} a(n)$ only makes sense for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. However it can evaluate to a complex result when $a(n)\in\mathbb{C}$ (e.g. $a(n)=\chi _{5,2}(n)=\{0,1,i,-i,-1,...\}$.

Comment: Is not the question about extending $a(n)$ to an analytic function of $n$? Risomar Sousa extends it to an entire function, i. e. finds a series that converges for all complex $n$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Also note in $F_a(s)=s\int\limits_0^\infty f_a(x)\,x^{-s-1}\,dx=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a(n)\ n^{-s}$, the integral is over real $x$. The inverse relationship is $f_a(s)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int\limits_{c-i\,\infty}^{c+i\,\infty} F_a(s)\frac{x^s}{s}\,ds$ where $F_a(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a(n)\ n^{-s}$ converges for $Re(s)>b$ and $c>b$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes the original question was about extending $a(n)$ to the analytic function $\tilde{a}(x)$ where $x\in\mathbb{C}$. My revelation was that $\tilde{a}(x)$ is just $\frac{1}{2}\tilde{f}_a'(x)$ evaluated at the frequency $f=1$. At this point I really don't understand if or why not $\tilde{f}_a'(x)$ and/or $\tilde{f}_a(x)$ extend to $x\in\mathbb{C}$ when evaluated at frequencies $f>1$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I suspect $\tilde{f}_a'(x)$ and $\tilde{f}_a(x)$ are analytic when evaluated at any finite evaluation frequency $f$, but only converge as $f\to\infty$ when $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I believe the relationship $\tilde{a}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\tilde{f}_a'(x)$ when $\tilde{f}_a'(x)$ is evaluated at the frequency $f=1$ generalizes to $\tilde{a}(x)=\frac{1}{2\,f}\tilde{f}_a'(x)$ when $\tilde{f}_a'(x)$ is evaluated at a finite frequency $f>1$.

Comment: I don't understand. If $f=1$ gives what you want why do you need anything else?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I don't think evaluating $\tilde{a}(x)$ at non-integer values of $x$ is of much value since there are an infinite number of functions that evaluate correctly at integer values of $x$ but which generally evaluate very differently at non-integer values of $x$. Therefore I don't really see the point in extending $a(n)$ to a complex analytic function $\tilde{a}(x)$ where $x\in\mathbb{C}$. I think the real value in the paper is it lead to formulas (f) and (g) above for $\tilde{f}_a(x)$ and $\tilde{f}_a'(x)$.

Comment: While I see some interest in finding entire functions with given values at natural numbers *and* explicit arithmetically interesting coefficients with potential applications for number theory, I don't see any significance in these (f) and (g).

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I'm sorry my point seems to be lost on you. The significance of formulas (f) and (g) is that they're real analytic formulas for $\tilde{f}_a(x)$ and ${f}'(x)$. Are you also uninterested in real analytic formulas such as von Mangoldt's explicit formula for the second Chebyshev function: $\psi_o(x)=x-\sum\limits_\rho\frac{x^\rho}{\rho}-\log(2\,\pi)-\frac{1}{2}\,\log\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ where $\psi(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  Formula (f) for $\tilde{f}_a(x)$, when evaluated with $a(n)=\Lambda(n)$ where $F_a(s)=-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$, gives an alternate real analytic formula for $\psi(x)$. The von Mangold explicit formula only converges for $x>1$ whereas formula (f) for $\tilde{f}_a(x)$ converges for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Real analytic formulas for $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x} a(n)$ are hard to come by.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Whereas von Mangoldt's explicit formula illustrates the connection between the primes and the zeros of $\zeta(s)$ (which are the poles of $-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$), formula (f) for $\tilde{f}_a(x)$ illustrates the connection between the primes and the values of $F_a(s)=-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ at even positive integer values of $s$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე As the simplest possible example, I consider a real analytic formula for the Dirac delta function $\delta(x-1)$ far more important than a complex analytic formula for the Kronecker delta function $\delta_{n-1}$ derived from partial evaluation of the $\delta(x-1)$ formula.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Real analytic formulas for $\delta(x-1)$ can be used to derive complex analytic formulas for a variety of functions via Mellin convolutions such as $f(y)=\int\limits_0^\infty\delta(x-1)\ f\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\ \frac{dx}{x}$ and $f(y)=\int\limits_0^\infty\delta(x-1)\ f(y\ x)\ dx$ which generally converge for $Re(y)>0$ (e.g. see formulas (52) to (70) in the answer I posted to my own question on Math StackExchange at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2380164).